# Язык для быстрых операций над массивами

Tags: php, массивы, любой-язык, синтаксис

Посоветуйте язык, синтаксис схожий с PHP, который будет быстро производить операции с массивами.

Произвожу сравнения нескольких массивов, размерами порядка 200 на 200, и сил нету ждать пока на PHP исполнится код. Может есть какой-то язык, который и считать будет намного быстрее и специально ради одной задачи учить его не придётся?

Comment: 200 на 200 -- довольно маленькие размеры. У вас наверняка проблема с алгоритмом.

Comment: (Смотря на тег «PHP») А что подразумевается под массивами? А то то, что в PHP зовут «массивами» это, в общем-то, пес поймет что и ручка сбоку.

Comment: @drdaeman некий array[$x][$y]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу ваших комментариев, простите не заметил раньше. А что вы хотите получить в результате работы алгоритма?

---

Могу предложить два пути. Второй интереснее, но не для каждой задачи может быть применен. Пробуйте.

1.У РНР нет типизации переменных, поэтому он тратит кучу ресурсов, на то, чтобы разобраться "а шо это и шо с ним делать"))

Прирост быстродействия вы ощутите даже на Ruby или Java, не говоря уже о компилируемых типа C++))

Насчет похожести по синтаксису... Ну есть очень близкий Perl - он тоже часто бывает на хостингах... Но я не уверен, что вы сходу напишите на нем программу - он все-таки сильно отличается.. Да и к быстродействию тоже есть вопросы.

Я бы все же рекомендовал реализовать основной функционал на РНР, а сами операции сравнения реализовать на C++ и вызывать их через CGI-интерфейс редиректами...

2.И второй момент - попробуйте построить данные так (даже если где-то прийдется переразбить на несколько и т.п.), чтобы у вас отработали стандартные функции РНР `array_intersect` и `array_diff` - они будут работать гораздо быстрее вложенных циклов.

Answer (score 3):

[@trashmajor](/users/10933/trashmajor), т.е. Вы ищете (видимо во вложенных циклах) матрицу размером порядка 100х100 внутри матрицы размером 200х200, урезаете первую (если не нашли) и все повторяется?

Боюсь, что (особенно если дело доходит до фазы урезания столбцов матрицы 2) никакой язык не поможет кардинально ускорить процесс.

Видимо надо переработать алгоритм. Для начала я бы подумал о поиске правого нижнего элемента массива-2 в массиве-1 и сравнивал матрицы уже от этой точки.

Вообще-то тут многое зависит от "природы" данных. А также, как часто Вы ищете разные исходные матссив-2 в **одном и том же** массиве-1?

Если часто, то можно подумать об индексировании элементов массива-1 для ускорения поиска начальных точек для сравнения матриц.

Answer (score 2):

C, C++.
Может быть стоит оптимизировать алгоритм? Действительно, как писали, ваши размеры малы для того, чтобы начинать ругаться на PHP.

Comment: Я сначала ищу массив-2 в массиве-1, если не нахожу, удаляю строку из массива-2 и снова ищу в массиве-1. Продолжаю удалять по строке пока не найду массив-2 в массиве-1. Если строка остаётся одна, возвращаю строки назад и удаляю столбец из массива-2. Снова ищу. Удаляю по столбцу, пока не найду.

Comment: можно для начала не удалять столбец/строку, а просто поправить индексы для цикла. Это даст ускорение. 

Но если удаляете строки (я так понимаю верхнюю?) то может начать поиск снизу вверх до первого различия? и удалять не нужно будет.